# What is the alt code for Fullwidth Colon?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Can't seem to find it anywhere.
Or is there another way to type this character (without copy pasting it all the time) ? - 
：

Answer (score 1):

[Unicode FF1A: Unicode Character 'FULLWIDTH COLON' (U+FF1A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1a/index.htm)

In Wordpad, press the space bar (or be at the start of a new file), and type:
<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

(Ignore the fact that those letters show up on the screen.)

Then hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and press <kbd>X</kbd>.

Tested in Windows 7, this changed the hex digits to the desired symbol.

To get that into Notepad, use Copy (from Wordpad) and Paste (into Notepad).

How I found this: reading Method #4 from [Entering Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm).

Want a more efficient way?  I found <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>) worked fine in Wordpad.  That might have only been after I added these commands to manipulate the registry.  (The following registry changes affect the value documented by Method #1 of the prior hyperlink.)

Run:

`reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method" /v EnableHexNumpad
reg ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method" /v EnableHexNumpad /T REG_SZ /d 1
reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method" /v EnableHexNumpad`

Although, I rather suspect that didn't impact things.  (I probably needed to Restart Windows, or at least Wordpad, and didn't do either.)

Notepad doesn't seem to support either of these methods.  Yay Notepad.  Yeah, maybe that seems like it isn't as easy as it should be.  Sometimes, when dealing with proprietary closed-source software, that's what you just gotta deal with.  Best to accept reality, and move onto finding a solution that does work (like Wordpad).

Case in point: I had absolutely no luck with trying to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (using the numpad's plus sign), which was documented with Method #1 of the prior hyperlink.  So, I kept toying around until I did find a working solution.  Personally, I think that modern Windows should have an easy way to type any Unicode character.  However, the experts who made the fileformat.info site say (in the [Entering Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) guide), about Method #1, that "some readers report that this method didn't work for them".  Also, the guide says, "it seems like none of these methods are really universal."  So Windows seems to not have made this functionality very sufficient.  If Windows did, then other programs like Wordpad and Word would probably not have extra code that implements a workaround by using a secret/hidden/undocumented <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> key combination.  Since these programs do have such a solution, I strongly suspect this may well be the best available solution (at least for some characters, on some systems).

As for Firefox, like Notepad, if you want to enter such a character, it seems perfectly capable of easily pasting the character once you generate it with another program.  Here is an instance, which you may be able to easily copy...

：

(You cannot simply use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> trick to enter that character directly in Firefox.  As noted by [Hitesh12's first comment to Paul's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/1086238/what-is-the-alt-code-for-fullwidth-colon/1086263#comment-1536999), that seems to just create this → right arrow character, when Hitest12 tried it, and when I tried it in Firefox 46.0.1 Funnelcake Jul 2012 mozilla11 - 1.0 in Win7x64.)

Answer (score 0):

The unicode for FULLWIDTH_COLON is U+FF1A.

FF1A is hex, so use your calculator to convert this to decimal - 65306

Open up Wordpad, Word, or another Office app, and hold Alt down and type 65306 on the numpad.

Comment: I did that and this comes up
→ (arrow)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Hitesh12  Are you doing this in Word?  If you are on Windows, only a few apps will do extended unicode alt codes

Comment: This happens in word, notepad, browser (chrome, firefox) etc. Looks like basically everywhere.

Comment: @Hitesh12 Word is the only app in that list that it should be expected to work in.  What version is it?

Comment: So you are saying this is one of those few extended unicode alt codes. Isn't there something else I can do ? Any registry change ? Any external software ? What about AutoHotkey ?

Comment: Most unicode codes are extended.  Native windows only understands alt codes up to 255.  Recent versions of office apps should work, and so should wordpad.

Comment: I am using Libreoffice writer (not microsoft word). Will it make a difference ? Lets say I want to use this character in folder and file names. Can I do it ?

Comment: You are right, wordpad is the only place so far where this worked

Comment: I think Windows supports the use of unicode filenames, but ultimately it is up to the filesystem - NTFS should work.  The issue is entering alt-codes, which can only be done from supporting apps . Otherwise you are going to have to cut and paste.

Comment: To type alt+hex code in Windows you need to enable hex numpad like [this](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc  Thanks - feel free to edit the answer and add that in.

Comment: @Paul this doesn't work with Indian keyboard settings, which is what (presumably) Hitesh is using...

Comment: @Rahul2001 Hitesh has reported he was able to get it working Wordpad, four replies up.